# Why is my program not printing the outputs for the specified input?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a grid that looks like this:
[image]

What my program does is that it will calculate whether or not a badge is earned then, it will print out a yes or a no if the badge is earned or not for a particular input (input will be a box with the coordinates (x, y)). But for some reason, when I go to print my outputs, my program is only calculating it for the region that's shaded yellow.

In my code, I've accounted for the boxes not on the edge by saying:

```
if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19))
```

But this doesn't seem to fix my problem. NOTE: If the input (x, y) aren't in the interval [1, 20], then I return a -1.

Here's what I get when I print my results:
[image]

As you can see, the outputs for the silver badges in a field NOT on the edge doesn't show up. I just can't seem to figure out why boxes not on the edge aren't being calculated/printed out.

*NOTE:* The Poly badge returns a "yes" when a field earns TWO OR MORE bronze badges.

*NOTE:* The Any Color badge returns a badge if:

1. A field earns 0 bronze badges and if all neighboring fields earn no bronze badges (neighboring fields include northwest, northeast, southwest, and southeast)
2. A field earns 1 bronze badge and it's overall field score (declared as fieldScore) is 20 or above.
3. A field earns 2 bronze badges and AT LEAST one of the following is true: the field does not turn any profit (declared as fieldProfit), it takes less than 80 days to harvest (declared as harvestTime), or its sun exposure (declared as sunExposure) is greater than its irrigation exposure (declared as irrigationExposure).
4. A field earns 3 or more bronze badges and if at least two of its direct neighbors earn two or more bronze badges. (direct neighbors are north, south, east, and west).

Here's my code for the two silver badge functions (Poly badge and Any Color badge):

```
int countBadges(int x, int y) {
   int mavebadge, incirclebadge, herobadge, weatherbadge, inquattrobadge,
      total;

   mavebadge = badgeBoundaryMaven(x, y);
   incirclebadge = badgeInnerCircle(x, y);
   herobadge = badgeLocalHero(x, y);
   weatherbadge = badgeBoringWeather(x, y);
   inquattrobadge = badgeInQuattro(x, y);

   total = mavebadge + incirclebadge + herobadge + weatherbadge +
      inquattrobadge;

   return total;

   printf("Total number: %d\n", countBadges(2, 2));
}

int badgePoly(int x, int y) {
   int bronzebadges, polybadge;

   if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {
      bronzebadges = countBadges(x, y);
      if (bronzebadges >= 2) {
         polybadge = 1;
      }
      else {
         polybadge = 0;
      }
   }
   else {
      polybadge = -1;
   }

   return polybadge;
}


int badgeAnyColor(int x, int y) {
   int bronzebadges, northbadges, northeastbadges, northwestbadges, eastbadges,
      westbadges, southbadges, southeastbadges, southwestbadges, colorbadge;

   double fs, ht, fp, sunexp, irrexp;

   if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {
      fs = fieldScore(x, y);
      ht = harvestTime(x, y);
      fp = fieldProfit(x, y);
      sunexp = sunExposure(x, y);
      irrexp = irrigationExposure(x, y);
      bronzebadges = countBadges(x, y);
      northbadges = countBadges(x, y + 1);
      northeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y + 1);
      northwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y + 1);
      eastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y);
      westbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y);
      southbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y - 1);
      southeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y - 1);
      southwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y - 1);

      switch (bronzebadges) {
         case 0: {
            if (x == 1 && y == 1){
               if (northbadges == 0 && northeastbadges == 0 &&
                  eastbadges == 0){
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if (x == 20 && y == 1) {
               if (northbadges == 0 && northwestbadges == 0 &&
                  westbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
           }
            if (x == 1 && y == 20) {
               if (eastbadges == 0 && southeastbadges == 0 &&
                  southbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
           }
            if (x == 20 && y == 20) {
               if (westbadges == 0 && southwestbadges == 0 &&
                  southbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && (y == 1)) {
               if (westbadges == 0 && northwestbadges == 0 && northbadges == 0
                  && northeastbadges == 0 && eastbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && (y == 20)) {
               if (westbadges == 0 && southwestbadges == 0 && southbadges == 0
                  && southeastbadges == 0 && eastbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x == 20) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19)) {
               if (northbadges == 0 && northwestbadges == 0 &&
                  westbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x == 1) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19)) {
               if (northbadges == 0 && northeastbadges == 0 && eastbadges == 0
                  && southeastbadges == 0 && southbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19)) {
               if (northbadges == 0 && northwestbadges == 0 && westbadges == 0
                  && southwestbadges == 0 && southbadges == 0 &&
                     southeastbadges == 0 && eastbadges == 0 &&
                        northeastbadges == 0) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            break;
         }
         case 1: {
            if (fs >= 20) {
               colorbadge = 1;
            }
            else {
               colorbadge = 0;
            }
            break;
         }
         case 2: {
            if (fp <= 0 || ht < 80 || sunexp > irrexp) {
               colorbadge = 1;
            }
            else {
               colorbadge = 0;
            }
            break;
         }
         case 3:
         case 4:
         case 5: {
            if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && y == 1) {
               if (((westbadges + northbadges) >= 2) || ((northbadges +
                  eastbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges + eastbadges) >= 2)) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if (x == 1 && y == 1) {
               if ((northbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if (x == 20 && y == 1) {
               if ((northbadges + westbadges) >= 2) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if (x == 1 && y == 20) {
               if ((southbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if (x == 20 && y == 20) {
               if ((southbadges + westbadges) >= 2) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && y == 20) {
               if (((westbadges + southbadges) >= 2) || ((southbadges +
                  eastbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges + eastbadges) >= 2)) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x == 1) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19)) {
               if (((northbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) || ((eastbadges +
                  southbadges) >= 2) || ((northbadges + southbadges) >= 2)) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x == 20) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19)) {
               if (((northbadges + westbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges +
                  southbadges) >= 2) || ((northbadges + southbadges) >= 2)) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && (y >= 2 && y <= 19)) {
               if (((northbadges + westbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges +
                  southbadges) >= 2) || ((southbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) ||
                     ((northbadges + southbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges +
                        eastbadges) >= 2)) {
                  colorbadge = 1;
               }
               else {
                  colorbadge = 0;
               }
            }
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   else {
      colorbadge = -1;
   }
   return colorbadge;
}
```

Comment: Probably not related, but your `if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {` allows `x` and `y` to be `20`, however further down you call `northeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y + 1)`, possibly shipping in `21`.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thanks for catching that!

Comment: No problems. I would recommend that you refactor your code a bit, there are a lot of simplifications that can be done. You can remove a ton of equal `else` statements, like `else { colorbadge = 0; ...`. Just put `colorbadge = 0` on top and skip the `else` statements, for instance. It will also make you think through the logic, solution will most likely show itself then too ;)

Comment: OH! Good idea! What could be the problem that's causing it not to print though?? Any ideas? :)

Comment: Your countBadges() function takes coordinates, but it would help if you showed the grid declaration, and one of the inner functions (badgeBoundaryMaven, badgeInnerCircle, badgeLocalHero, etc), to determine whether you have boundary addressing problem(s).

Comment: Please provide the loop which you run through all of the grid locations, and we can look at whether all grid coordinates are visited.

Comment: Do you want to see the loops inside the inner functions? Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your countBadges(x,y) function has a return statement prior to the printf, so that printf will never print.  You should move it above return, and comment it out if you don't need it.  you may have other issues with printf.

```
int countBadges(int x, int y)
{
    int mavebadge, incirclebadge, herobadge, weatherbadge, inquattrobadge,
        total;

    mavebadge = badgeBoundaryMaven(x, y);
    incirclebadge = badgeInnerCircle(x, y);
    herobadge = badgeLocalHero(x, y);
    weatherbadge = badgeBoringWeather(x, y);
    inquattrobadge = badgeInQuattro(x, y);

    total = mavebadge + incirclebadge + herobadge + weatherbadge +
        inquattrobadge;

    printf("Total number: %d\n", countBadges(2, 2));
    return total;
}
```

You check your grid location often, so I would suggest a function (or macro), ongrid(x,y), and use it to check valid grid boundary location,

```
int ongrid(x,y)
{
    return ( (x>=1) && (x<=20) && (y>=1) && (y<=20) );
}
```

You also should check your boundary conditions,

```
  if( y + 1<=20 )
      northbadges = countBadges(x, y + 1);
  if( x + 1<=20 && y + 1<=20 )
     northeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y + 1);
  if( x - 1>=1 && y + 1<=20 )
     northwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y + 1);
  if( x + 1<=20 )
     eastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y);
  if( x - 1<=20 )
     westbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y);
  if( y - 1>=1 )
     southbadges = countBadges(x, y - 1); //this value was probably not right
  if( x + 1<=20 && y - 1>=1 )
     southeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y - 1);
  if( x - 1>=1 && y - 1>=1 )
     southwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y - 1);
```

Rewritten with the ongrid() function for more clarity,

```
  if( ongrid(x,y + 1) )
      northbadges = countBadges(x, y + 1);
  if( ongrid(x + 1,y + 1) )
     northeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y + 1);
  if( ongrid(x - 1,y + 1) )
     northwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y + 1);
  if( ongrid(x + 1,y) )
     eastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y);
  if( ongrid(x - 1,y) )
     westbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y);
  if( ongrid(x,y - 1) )
     southbadges = countBadges(x, y - 1);
  if( ongrid(x + 1,y - 1) )
     southeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y - 1);
  if( ongrid(x - 1,y - 1) )
     southwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y - 1);
```

Your switch statement for bronze badges does not have a default; you need to handle the default in case your have a different number of badges than explicitly stated,

```
     default : {
         break;
     }
```